# How to read .txt file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been learning JS and I have a problem:

How can i assigned data from input.txt to variable a
Help me.

I've searched online and YouTube, but I still can't find a answer

[image: screenshot of two files open in editor]

Comment: What's the runtime environment? How and where are you running the scripts? Browser, Node.js, Deno, Rhino, ...? JavaScript doesn't have functionality for reading files. Usually the runtime environment provides some functions. **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—** [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using HTML, you can use fetch:

```js
fetch('input.txt')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

You could also use this in an async context:

```js
async function getInput() {
  let res = await fetch("input.txt");
  let text = await res.text();
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')
const contents = readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')
```